# How can I detect the scrollbar is dragged/clicked in a Jscrollpane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a Jscrollpane with a Jpanel inside. In this Jpanel I draw some shapes. The problem I have is when I scroll up and down. The drawing on the Jpanel appears cut. So I want to redraw the Jpanel every time I drag the scrollbar or click the direction arrows. How can I do it?
(Excuse me for not posting a SCCE, I've generated the interface with netbeans and it's quite complicated)

Comment: What have you done so far? Your code ? Also I think you should not have to re-draw the image every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this Jpanel I draw some shapes. The problem I have is when I scroll
>   up and down. The drawing on the Jpanel appears cut. So I want to
>   redraw the Jpanel every time I drag the scrollbar or click the
>   direction arrows.

- good idea in the case that you [repainting concrete Rectangle, Dimension for this Rectangle returns JViewport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

> I have a Jscrollpane with a Jpanel inside. In this Jpanel I draw some
>   shapes. The problem I have is when I scroll up and down.

- use [AdjustmentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/AdjustmentListener.html) added to [JScrollBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html) (derived directly from [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#operation) or as local variable)